# populate datagrid columns between two template fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datagrid "dgData" `AutoGenereateColumns="true"`

In this i have 2 templateFields.

Now i want to populate all the data between these 2 template fields.

How can i do this using C#

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Nothing. I am confused what code to write and in which datagrid event